# Unable to construct command from the output of ps

Tags: awk, string, ps, posix

I wish to get the httpd process and then get the `bin\apachectl` command/file -v output

Output:

```
ps -eo cmd | grep httpd | grep -v grep
/home/myapache/app/httpd/bin/httpd -k start
/home/myapache/app/httpd/bin/httpd -k start
/home/myapache/app/httpd/bin/httpd -k start
```

Output of `ps -eo cmd | grep httpd | grep -v grep | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'` is

```
/home/myapache/app/httpd/bin/httpd
```

My requirement is so fire the below command using `ps` command above.

```
/home/myapache/app/httpd/bin/apachectl -v
```

Below is what i could get so far.

```
dirname `ps -eo cmd | grep httpd | grep -v grep | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'` && echo -n "/apachectl -v
```

Output:

```
/home/myapache/app/httpd/bin
/apachectl -v
```

Unfortunately `/apachectl -v` appears in the next line when i want it to on the same line like below:

Requirement to execute the below command by constructing it using `ps`  preferably for posix:

```
/home/myapache/app/httpd/bin/apachectl -v
```

Comment: Hi Ashar, if you could please provide the output of `ps -ax | grep httpd` and tell us what exactly you wanna do it would be better. btw, you can `OUTPUT=/home/myapache/app/httpd/bin` and `APACHE='apachectl -v'` then easily concat two variables  `echo $OUTPUT/$APACHE`. also you can format `ps` instead of many pipes like `ps -eo cmd`.

Comment: storing it is variables will make is script like .. i wanted a single liner command .... but you have understood my requirement correctly.@binarysta

Comment: @binarysta  i provided the output and updated the original post. Kindly check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ps -eo cmd` does what you want, it seems like what you need is:

```
"$(ps -eo cmd | awk 'sub("/[h]ttpd[^/]*$",""){print; exit}')"/apachectl -v
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run it in one line like

```
PS_OUTPUT=`dirname $(ps -eo cmd | grep [h]ttpd | head -1|awk '{print $1}')`; APACHE='apachectl -v'; myCMD='$OUTPUT/$APACHE'; eval $myCMD
```

`eval`: executes the argument like a shell command

Comment: The problem is `PS_OUTPUT=dirname $(ps -eo cmd | grep [h]ttpd | head -1|awk '{print $1}'); ` actually executes the output of `ps` rather than  treating it as an input for `dirname` Can u please suggest ?

Comment: yes, I edited. it is correct now.

Comment: You should copy/paste that script into http://shellcheck.net to learn about **some** of the issues but there are others too, e.g. `grep [h]ttpd | head -1|awk '{print $1}'` can be done with just 1 command, `awk '/[h]ttpd/{print $1; exit}'` but you should probably be using `pgrep` instead anyway and it's unlikely that the `eval` command is what you really should be using.